# Filter results recommenderlab

Tags: r, recommendation-engine

I'm trying to evaluate the results of several recommendation methods from recommenderlab and I need to make post-processing to "results" and "pre" variables can someone explain me how can I do this?

```
scheme <- evaluationScheme(d, method="split", train = .9, k=1)
algorithms <- list(
     "random items" = list(name="RANDOM", param=NULL),
     "popular items" = list(name="POPULAR",param=NULL)
     )
results <- evaluate(scheme, algorithms_binary, n=c(1, 3))


rec <- Recommender(getData(scheme, "train"), method="UBCF")
pre<-predict(rec, getData(scheme, "known"), n=3)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to reimplement the functions of recommenderlab. You can find them on cran of the r-forge.